# Threads 'std::system_error' what() Operation not permitted

Tags: c++

I have a problem with an exception in my code with threads. Basically it´s a producer-consumer problem, with the difference that the consumers have to empty their own queues first, before consuming from the main one, plus that depending on the value, they add the number to the other consumer queue or process it.

The code works like intended, but after a random time running throws the following error:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
   what():  Operation not permitted`

I run out of ideas, sometimes it processes 6 values, others 600.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <fstream>
#include <queue>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

queue<int> main_queue;
queue<int> baker_queue;
queue<int> groceries_queue;
mutex mutex1;



void clients_arrival(){
    int random;
    int random_2;
    int i=0;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    while(true){
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(mutex1);
        random = 1+(rand()%3);
        random_2 = 100+(rand()%1200);
        main_queue.push(random);cout << "arrives client number "<<i+1<<" and has value "<<main_queue.back() << endl;
        locker.unlock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(random_2));
        i++;
    }
}


void baker_reception() {
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(mutex1);
        if (!main_queue.empty()) {
            if (baker_queue.empty()) {
                int a = main_queue.front();
                main_queue.pop();
                baker_queue.push(a);
                cout << "baker empty, it removed an " << baker_queue.front() << endl;
                if (a == 2) {
                    int b = a;
                    groceries_queue.push(b);
                    baker_queue.pop();
                }
                if (a == 3) {
                    int b = 2;
                    groceries_queue.push(b);
                    baker_queue.pop();
                }
                if (a == 1) {
                    baker_queue.pop();
                }
                locker.unlock();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
            }
            if (!baker_queue.empty()) {
                cout << "baker not empty, removed an " << baker_queue.front() << endl;
                int a = baker_queue.front();
                if (a == 2) {
                    int b = a;
                    groceries_queue.push(b);
                    baker_queue.pop();
                }
                if (a == 3) {
                    int b = 2;
                    groceries_queue.push(b);
                    baker_queue.pop();
                }
                if (a == 1) {
                    baker_queue.pop();
                }
                locker.unlock();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
            }
        }
        else {
            locker.unlock();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
        }
    }
}void groceries_reception() {
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(mutex1);
        if(!main_queue.empty()){
            if (groceries_queue.empty()) {
                int a = main_queue.front();
                main_queue.pop();
                groceries_queue.push(a);
                cout << "Groceries empty, it removed an " << groceries_queue.front() << endl;
                if (a == 1) {
                    int b = a;
                    baker_queue.push(b);
                    groceries_queue.pop();
                }
                if (a == 3) {
                    int b = 1;
                    baker_queue.push(b);
                    groceries_queue.pop();
                }
                if (a == 2) {
                    groceries_queue.pop();
                }
                locker.unlock();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
            }
            if (!groceries_queue.empty()) {
                cout << "Groceries not empty, removed an " << groceries_queue.front() << endl;
                int a = groceries_queue.front();
                if (a == 1) {
                    baker_queue.push(a);
                    groceries_queue.pop();
                }
                if (a == 3) {
                    int b = 1;
                    baker_queue.push(b);
                    groceries_queue.pop();
                }
                if (a == 2) {
                    groceries_queue.pop();
                }
                locker.unlock();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
            }
        }
        else {
            locker.unlock();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
        }
    }
}




int main() {
    std::thread client(clients_arrival);
    std::thread groceries(groceries_reception);
    std::thread baker(baker_reception);
    client.join();
    baker.join();
    groceries.join();
}
```

Comment: Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Specifically learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes and exceptions. That will help you locate when and where the exception is thrown, and from there you could find out where in your code it happens.

Comment: Far too much code here! Present a [MCVE] please. I recognise that this is difficult with a rarely-observed problem. Still.

Comment: All that manual mutex-juggling in complex conditionals is leading to you unlocking a mutex that isn't locked. You need to be more careful and you should learn about scoped locks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::system_error` is thrown either by the `std::thread` constructor or by one of the `unlock`s.

Since you say that the program starts the threads properly, the latter is the problem. `unlock` throws `std::system_error` if there is no associated mutex or the mutex is not locked.

So in your case you are trying to unlock a mutex that is not locked, e.g. because you unlocked it before already.

Look at `groceries_reception`. If you take the first `if (groceries_queue.empty())` branch you will unlock the mutex before the sleep. After the sleep you continue executing and the next `if` will be tested, which is `if (!groceries_queue.empty())`. Because other threads may have modified `groceries_queue` inbetween, now this branch may be taken as well. But in this branch you are calling `locker.unlock()` again. This is where the exception is thrown, because you are not actually holding the lock anymore.

The same problem is present in the other function. If you want to execute only one of the branches use `else if`.

However it would be much cleaner to let the lock unlock via its destructor at scope end. If you want to sleep after unlocking, simply make an artificial scope outside the lock's scope:

```
{
    unique_lock<mutex> locker(mutex1);
    // do something with lock, don't call unlock
}
std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
```

or you can put the sleep before taking the lock if its fine to happen at the first loop iteration's beginning:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(400));
unique_lock<mutex> locker(mutex1);
// do something with lock, don't call unlock
```